# jquery bxslider not working in ajax load contents that is print by jquery html()

Tags: ajax, bxslider

i have a bx-slider code and html content for slider in a file that is print by jquery html() in ajax request.

I.e

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider_wrap">

</div>

$.ajax({url: "return_data.php", success: function(result){   
            $('#slider_wrap').html(result); 
        }});
```

**return_data.php** have slider content and slider code

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }, 2000);
```